# How to upload a file from local machine to the SharePoint web site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm using **PowerShell v 5.1** How can I upload simple text file from my local machine to the corporate SharePoint? SharePoint URL when I'm on the needed web page looks like below:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/BlaBlaBla/AnotherBlaBlaBla/How%20To/Upload/FileToThisUrl.aspx?newTargetListUrl=%2blabla%2MyCompany%2Want%2FMe%20ToDoviewpath=%2This%2Impossible%2Task%2Uploading%20This%2FDocuments%2FTo%2SharePoint&id=%2FAnd%2FIHaveNoIdea%2How%2FTo%20Do%2FThis%20Job%20Reports

I've tried this script (suggested somewhere else don't remember where) but it throws an 403 error, and my credentials are correct I know it:

```
$credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

Function UploadToSharePoint{

$destination = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/BlaBlaBla/AnotherBlaBlaBla/How%20To/Upload/FileToThisUrl.aspx?newTargetListUrl=%2blabla%2MyCompany%2Want%2FMe%20ToDoviewpath=%2This%2Impossible%2Task%2Uploading%20This%2FDocuments%2FTo%2SharePoint&id=%2FAnd%2FIHaveNoIdea%2How%2FTo%20Do%2FThis%20Job%20Reports"
$File =Get-ChildItem  "C:\MyNameShouldBeHere\Work\PowerShell\UploadFileTest.txt"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials
$webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $File.Name, "PUT", $File.FullName)
```

According to [this microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) page there is no indication on **HOW TO SIMPLY UPLOAD A FILE TO THE SHAREPOINT**. They got bunch of other methods to do there, but not how to upload a file. Hence there is this information listed:

> Working with large files by using REST When you need to upload a
>   binary file that is larger than 1.5 megabytes (MB), the REST interface
>   is your only option. For a code example that shows you how to upload a
>   binary file that is smaller than 1.5 MB by using the SharePoint
>   JavaScript object model, see Complete basic operations using
>   JavaScript library code in SharePoint. The maximum size of a binary
>   file that you can create with REST is 2 gigabytes (GB).
>
> The following example shows how to create a large binary file.
>
> Warning
>
> This approach works only with Internet Explorer 10 and the latest
>   versions of other browsers.
>
> Copy url: http://site
>   url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder
>   Name')/Files/Add(url='file name', overwrite=true) method: POST body:
>   contents of binary file headers:
>       Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
>       X-RequestDigest: form digest value
>       content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
>       content-length:length of post body

My file is not that big, so not sure if I need to use this method? And what the h.. in the world Internet Explorer means in this context? Can you only upload the file using IE? What?

2 questions that arise in my head:

1. Do I need to get authorization token in order to use REST API to upload the file
2. Where in Sharepoint UI can I find this feature? Under My account? I've searched and didn't find anything that reminds this feature.
3. Was someone able to upload a file using PowerShell into the Sharepoint web site?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the PnP module for working with SharePoint via PowerShell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

More specifically, the Add-PnPFile cmdlet.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url $siteURL -UseWebLogin
Add-PnPFile -Path $localPathToFile -Folder $docLibName -Values @{Modified="1/1/2016", "Custom_x0020_Column"="Custom Value"}
```